# Redis "ResponseError: unknown command '502'"

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

When using redis-py (version 2.8.0) I'm getting this strange error (below). Does anyone have a clue why this might be happening?

```
return self.execute_command('GET', name)
File "..../lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 394, in execute_command
return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
File "..../python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 404, in parse_response
response = connection.read_response()
File ".../python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 316, in read_response
    raise response
ResponseError: unknown command '502'
```

Redis server version: 2.2.12, tried setting up redis-server to use unix socket and TCP, also tried downgrading redis-py module to 2.4, always get the same error.

With memcached cache engine I don't see anything like this.

Thanks.

Comment: 502 is the HTTP Response code for Bad Gateway. It sounds like you are getting a Bad Gateway error but then 502 is not one of the ones they have defined in the ResponseError Exception class.

Comment: Right and I'm using unix socket to connect with the server (at least the socket path is specified in the redis config via django settings.py file).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a very similar error in two setups I had as well. Upgrading both redis-server and the redis python packages worked for me.

Mine was also in `redis/connection.py`, in `read_response`, except with the error 
`ResponseError: ERR unknown command '2014-06-09'`

I was running `redis-server 2.8.4-2` on Ubuntu and `Python/2.7.6/` , with the python `redis` package `v 2.8.0`.

Also encountered this with [homebrew] redis-server 2.6.16 on Mac OS X , with `Python/2.7.6/` , with both the python redis package versions 2.8.0   and 2.10.1.

It wasn't until I upgraded both `redis-server` to `2.8.0` and python redis package to `2.10.1`, that the `unknown command` error went away.